Sonarlint on Eclipse Oxygen and Java 1.8.0
I'm trying to make Sonarlint works with my (old) project running on Java 1.8.0.
Downloaded the SonarLint for Eclipse 6.2.0.37299 version, as mentioned here (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarqube-ide) and Installed.
Configured the remote server to download all the rules from the remote server and...
Looking at the logs, something don't works as expected.
Load plugins
Plugin 'HTML Code Quality and Security' requires JRE 11 while current is 1.8. Skip loading it.
Plugin 'Java Code Quality and Security' requires JRE 11 while current is 1.8. Skip loading it.
Plugin 'JavaScript/TypeScript/CSS Code Quality and Security' requires JRE 11 while current is 1.8. Skip loading it.
Plugin 'PHP Code Quality and Security' requires JRE 11 while current is 1.8. Skip loading it.
Plugin 'Python Code Quality and Security' requires JRE 11 while current is 1.8. Skip loading it.
Load plugins (done) | time=48ms
Unable to start the SonarLint engine
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The plugin [kotlin] does not support Java 1.8.0_211
So, this means that the Rules requires java 11?
Is it possible to tell SonarLint to use Java11 instead of the "default" Java 8 installation?

requires JRE 11 seems pretty clear. Have you read SonarLint documentation to see what are the requirements? Research is expected before asking a question (see [ask]). Also JDK 1.8.0_211 was released in 2019. It is pretty outdated and unsecure today. Eclipse Oxygen was released in 2017. It probably supports up to JDK 10 only from what I see in its New and Noteworthy page.

The current Eclipse version 2024-12 supports development with Java 8. It is shipped with an embedded Java 21. So you just need to install Eclipse 2024-12 and can use the Java 8 installed on your system for your projects.

It's possible to provide a custom JRE for SonarLint Eclipse: https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube-for-ide/eclipse/team-features/advanced-configuration/#providing-a-java-runtime

@lopoto This would only be necessary if and only if you want to stick to an Eclipse version that is 27 releases and 7 years behind, which doesn't sound like a good idea.
